# Are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ and $B$ such that each row of $AB$ has a nonzero entry?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an $n_A \times n$ matrix and $B$ an $n \times n_B$ matrix. What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ and $B$ such that each row of $AB$ has a nonzero entry?

Comment: If all entries of $A$ are zero, than $\operatorname{rank}(A)=0$. If you have at least one entry which is nonzero, you have $\operatorname{rank}(A)\geq 1$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am interested in the other direction i.e. I want nonzero rows so does $Rank(AB) \geq k$ guarantee that each row has a nonzero entry.

Comment: In terms of condition on the rank, the only possible condition is that the rank are maximal, and equal to the dimension of the image space. The matrices $A=diag\{1, \dots ,1, 0,\dots 0\}$ and $B=diag\{0, \dots ,0, 1,\dots 1\}$. In terms of the second question, $|B^tA^te_i|^2>0$ is an equivalent condition.

Comment: Great. This is what I am looking for. So you are saying that if Rank$(A)=n_A$ and Rank$(B)=n$ then each row of $AB$ must have a nonzero element? Is there an easy proof for this. I don't understand why your last sentence is an equivalent condition, isn't it summing over entries in each row? (Not sure what is meant by the second sentence).

Comment: Hint: What would happen, if some row of $AB$ is zero? Could the rows of $A$ or $B$ be linearly independent?

Comment: @user251257. First note that $(AB)_{jk}=A_{j\cdot}B_{\cdot k}$. We can apply row operations to $A$ and column operations to $B$ until $A$ and $B$ are in reduced row echelon form. Now if after the reduction $A_{j\cdot} \neq 0$ and $B_{ \cdot j} \neq 0$ then $(AB)_{j\cdot}$ cannot be zero. Hence, I think for each row of $AB$ to have a nonzero entry a sufficient (and necessary?) condition is $Rank(A)=n_A$ and $Rank(B)=n$ i.e. rows of $A$ are linearly independent and columns of $B$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks... If my previous comment is the right idea, you can put this as the answer and I'll mark it correct (I can fill in details if you want to just put bare bones idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the $i$-th row of $AB$ is completely zero. That is, the $i$-th row $a_i$ of $A$ times $B$ is zero. Thus, either $a_i$ is zero or the rows of $B$ are linearly dependent.

Thus, the necessary and sufficient conditions that every row of $AB$ is not completely zero is: No row of $A$ is in the null space of $B^T$.

Each of following conditions is sufficient:

- Every row of $A$ is not completely zero and  $\operatorname{rank}(B)=n$; or
- $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n_A$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B) = n$.

Comment: Just to confirm (Rank$(A)=n_A$ & Rank$(B)=n$) $\Leftrightarrow$ No row of $AB$ is completely zero.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent solution, it helped me clarify exactly what I wanted.... I changed the question to reflect this.

Comment: But this is not necessary and sufficient. For example the matrices $A,B$ consisting of all ones fail this condition.

Comment: @user103828 my bad. I read the arrow wrong. it is only sufficient.

Comment: The question is asking for "necessary and sufficient conditions". Moreover, the first comment to your answer is a question by the OP asking if this is $\Leftrightarrow$, and you answered yes.

Comment: @N.S. the question have been edited. I have no mathjax here on smartphone and read the arrow wrong on the first sight

Comment: @N.S. I changed the question after the comment... Is there an easy fix? So just to confirm,  (Rank$(A)=n_A$ & Rank$(B)=n)$ $\Rightarrow$ No row of $AB$ is completely zero.... no biggie if this is all that can be said. I only really want sufficiency.

Comment: @N.S so i update the answer to make it very clear.

Comment: @user251257 Actually, shouldn't it be column rank of $B$ is $n_B$ (instead of row rank is $n$), since $a_{ij}$ is multiplied by column $j$ of $B$?

Comment: @user103828 the $i$-th row of $AB$ is the linear combination of the *rows* of $B$ with coefficients given by the $i$-th row of $A$.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken $a_{i}$ is multiplied by rows of $B$.